# Why does appending to a BufferedReader interfere with InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream

The following code works:

```
    //Read from an input stream
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("13.png");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    /*
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    */


    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    Image image = ImageIO.read(is);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Yet there is an error if we uncomment the while loop which includes appending to a BufferedReader.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:63)
```

Why is so?

Comment: Seriously? You are trying to read a PNG file as lines? What do you expect from that? As a side note, it seems to be a common anti-pattern to mindlessly wrap streams into buffered streams without ever asking whether this has any benefit or even could downgrade the performance. You can bet, the ImageIO framework will already read the data in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

inputStream can only be read once.

```
// Doing this reads inputStream for the first time
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

// Doing this reads inputStream for the second time, resulting in the error
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

What you need to do is to open a new inputStream

```
FileInputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream("13.png");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream2);
Image image = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Comment: Or just use `ImageIO.read(new File("13.png"))` and let the framework deal with low-level details